# Angular directive attributes not being passed into scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, arguments

my angular directives' arguments aren't getting passed into the scope:

```
app.directive('sectionLeft', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
       sectionContent: '=',
       sectionImg: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/section_left.html'
  };
});

app.directive('sectionRight', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
       sectionContent: '=',
       sectionImg: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/section_right.html'
  };
});
```

They're called from here:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in data.home">
   <section-left ng-if="$even"  sectionContent="{{content}}" sectionImg="http://placehold.it/700x450"></div>
   <section-right ng-if="$odd" sectionContent="{{content}}" sectionImg="http://placehold.it/700x450"></div>
</div>
```

and look like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                {{sectionContent}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{sectionImg}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is just a blank space with no content, but I can see the attributes getting set on the directive element. What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to remove the `{{}}` to pass scope variables to directive using `=` in isolated scope.

```
section-content="content"
```

This will imply that the 2 way binding will be to a parent scope variable named `content`

Comment: I think that worked! I also named by parameters wrong on the element, should have been section-content. Many thanks!

Comment: ah yes...I didn't notice that myself

Comment: I've constantly pondered the reason why firebase converts camel case to hiphenation, surely it's an uneccessary overhead?

Comment: simplification of object keys. Can't write `object.some-property` but hyphenated is easier to read

Comment: I suppose, but doesn't the confusion caused by them sort of outweigh the clearer property name?